# can we see html localstorage content through client browser?

Tags: asp.net, html, jsp

supppose I use html5 local storage for my website.

1)can End user see my local storage values through browser using view source code etc?

2)How can we enter data for HTML5 local storage as domain level, i dont want to add my records manually when page loads everytime?

3where will HTML5 local storage content  be saved?
                      I)in client side?
                      II)in server side(webserver)

anyhelp please?

Comment: Here : http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/ and http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/

Comment: Also in chrome, just right click => Inspect Element => Resources => local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not through view source, but many Developer Tools support this. So yes, a user could very easy figure out what the contents of their browser's localStorage is. For example, in Chrome, open the Developer Tools, and on the Resources tab select "Local Storage"
2. I think what you are asking for is "How to I add local storage without writing the code in every page". You would typically then put that code in a common .js file - and reference it whenever you needed it. If you need it in every page, then depending on which platform you are using, they probably have some sort of "master". ASP.NET WebForms has Master Pages, ASP.NET MVC has ViewStart, etc.
3. Client side. It's *local* storage - as in it is local to the browser.

Comment: is it possible to connect DB which is in server and getdata  through either javascript or HTML5?

Comment: @youCanCheatMe That is an entirely different question. I'd suggest making a new question out of that instead, or seeing of someone else has already asked that.